# How to Fix EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS crashes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Unfortunately, I'm getting some crashes (I can't reproduce) from the live application. I've tried very different things for closure like adding *[weak self]* or making *strong self* in the closure but none of them works.

Only thing I'm sure that users crash after coming back to the application after a long time (15min to 1hour). I ran different Zombie and Allocation tests in the Instruments but there's no clue about the leaks.

I'd like to know if there's a logical way to detect the reason of EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS crashes. How can I add a check to prevent the crash or debug the problem? Can you please suggest me something?

waterfallResponse property is crashing while setting the data object in the *refreshAd* call.

```
@objc public class AdMediatorBanner {

...// properties
var waterfallResponse: AdMediatorZoneResponse?

...// code blocks

    AdMediatorManager.instance.refreshAd(self.zoneId!, self.adMediatorBannerId!) { [weak self] (data, errorCode) in
                guard let self = self else {
                    return
                }
                if data != nil {
                    self.waterfallResponse = data
                }

... // rest of closure code blocks
```

Crash Log:

```
Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x1320da410 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19bc67d90 objc_release + 16
1  XXX                            0x104c213e4 destroy for AdMediatorZoneResponseItem + 4309242852 (<compiler-generated>:4309242852)
2  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1a9a473a0 swift_arrayDestroy + 84
3  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1a979e390 _ContiguousArrayStorage.__deallocating_deinit + 48
4  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1a9a5200c _swift_release_dealloc + 36
5  XXX                            0x104c54cac outlined consume of AdMediatorZoneResponse? + 4309453996 
6  XXX                            0x104c4e7d0 AdMediatorBanner.waterfallResponse.setter + 51 (AdMediatorBanner.swift:51)
7  XXX                            0x104c55910 partial apply for closure #2 in AdMediatorBanner.startAdRequest() + 353 (AdMediatorBanner.swift:353)
8  XXX                            0x104c3cc14 partial apply for closure #1 in AdMediatorManager.refreshAd(_:_:completionHandler:) + 96 (AdMediatorManager.swift:96)
9  XXX                            0x104cb5f9c partial apply for closure #1 in AdMediatorWebRequest.fetchDataFromServer(resultHandler:) + 4309852060 (<compiler-generated>:4309852060)
10 XXX                            0x104cb4e84 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed Data?, @guaranteed NSURLResponse?, @guaranteed Error?) -> () + 4309847684 (<compiler-generated>:4309847684)
11 CFNetwork                      0x19f1f5b18 CFNetServiceBrowserSearchForServices + 96332
12 CFNetwork                      0x19f206948 _CFHTTPMessageSetResponseProxyURL + 8176
13 Foundation                     0x19c30bcfc __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
14 Foundation                     0x19c20dc3c -[NSBlockOperation main] + 104
15 Foundation                     0x19c30e03c __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 24
16 Foundation                     0x19c20d914 -[NSOperation start] + 752
17 Foundation                     0x19c30ea68 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 24
18 Foundation                     0x19c30e528 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x19bbe4db4 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 144
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x19bbd833c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x19bbdaaf8 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 408
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x19bbda258 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 588
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x19bbe75c0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 348
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x19bbe7d9c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 116
25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19bc3f6d8 _pthread_wqthread + 216
26 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19bc459c8 start_wqthread + 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to assign `waterfallResponse` on main queue, like

```
if data != nil {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
       self?.waterfallResponse = data
    }
}
```

and make sure to do the same in all other possible places.

Comment: `[weak self]` is pointless. `DispatchQueue` closures don't cause retain cycles.

Comment: So are you suggest to make all the setter/getter operation of this property in a async/sync block because of accession of different threads? Do you suggest to read property in a sync block ? What does it make better (main async/sync or specific dispatch group)?

Comment: @Coldfish, not for all places, if you sure that you are on main queue, eg in UI actions, then there is no needs to wrap it in dispatch block, but if it is in any callback, completion closures, etc. (especially in calls to 3d party APIs) then it is definitely better to embed it in dispatch block. In provided code I'm dead sure it must be redirected to main queue. Provided crash log is highly probable caused by thread-safety issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, moving code to main thread doesn't work in the live app. Same crash is still occurring same as before.

Comment: @Coldfish so you've accepted this answer, did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

One helpful tip to find the reason of the crash, edit scheme -> Run -> Diagnostics
Then tick the address sanitizer, when you run in development the application will pause and show you a dead address was being used by a variable.